# build child and anchestor three from post parent

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, menus, meta-query, wp-list-pages

I'm trying to build a three menu from a custom post type, and wanna build a complet three from the posts children and parents, with all levels both up and down included.

And actually the function `wp_list_pages()`does that really great, and actually includes all levels that i want.

But i also want to modify the query a little, and exclude some post that fits within a meta query, that i'm using another place like this:

```
$meta_query[] = array(
    'relation' => 'or',
    array(                
        'key' => 'rank',
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'value' => 100,
    ),            
    array(                
        'key' => 'rank',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        'value' => 1,
    ),
);
```

The only problem is that `wp_list_pages()` don't support the meta_query, and only looking for at specific meta key and value.

Does anybody have a solution for this, or an idea to archive the goal?

Answer (score 0):

So i got it working, by adding a filter:

i added this before the wp_list_pages

```
add_filter( 'get_pages', 'check_propper_rank', 10, 2 );
wp_list_pages( array(
   'post_type' => 'wiki-term',
) );
```

and then created a new filter, to removed the ones that did'nt fit the rank.

```
function check_propper_rank( $pages, $arguments ) {
    
    $user_rank = 100;
    
    foreach ( $pages as $key => $page ) {
        $required_rank = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'rank', true);
        if ( $required_rank >= $user_rank ) {
            unset($pages[$key]);
        }
    }
    
    if ( empty( $pages ) )
        return $pages;

    // Remove instantly
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10 );

    return $pages;
}
```